# Dar formato de moneda a contenido de DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen día a todos, estoy intentando por medio de los siguientes codigos dar formato de moneda al contenido de varias celdas dentro de mi DataGridView lo cual no consigo, si pueden ayudarme estare muy agradecido.

```
    dgvListArtIng.Columns["PrecioUnitario"].DefaultCellStyle.Format= "C2";
    dgvListArtIng.Columns["SubtotalArticulo"].DefaultCellStyle.Format ="C2";

    dgvListArtIng.Columns["PrecioUnitario"].DefaultCellStyle.Format= "N2";
    dgvListArtIng.Columns["SubtotalArticulo"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";

    dgvListArtIng.Columns["PrecioUnitario"].DefaultCellStyle.Format= "##,##0.00";
    dgvListArtIng.Columns["SubtotalArticulo"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##,##0.00";
```

Cuando aplico alguna de estas opciones me sigue mostrando los valores de cada celda como enteros y necesito mostrarlos en formato moneda "$10,000.00".

Agrego el método que llena el DataGridView

```
 public void CargarGridArticulos()
    {
        #region Objetos
        DataTable dtCGArt = new DataTable();
        #endregion
        #region Variables
        int cantidad = 0;
        double preciounitario = 0;
        string descripcion = "";
        double subtotalArt = 0;
        #endregion
        #region ObtenerValores
        if (txtIngCantidad.Text != "")
        {
            cantidad = int.Parse(txtIngCantidad.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            cantidad = 0;
        }
        if (txtIngPU.Text != "")
        {
            preciounitario = double.Parse(txtIngPU.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            preciounitario = 0;
        }
        if (txtDescripcion.Text != "")
        {
            descripcion = txtDescripcion.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            descripcion = "";
        }
        if (cantidad >0 && preciounitario >0)
        {
            subtotalArt = cantidad * preciounitario;                
        }
        else
        {
            subtotalArt = 0;                    
        }
        #endregion
        #region ObtenerArticulo
        if (artId > 0)
        {
            dtCGArt = objConsultas.MuestraArticulosID(artId);
            if (dtCGArt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow drCGArt in dtCGArt.Rows)
                {
                    articulo = Convert.ToString(drCGArt[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region ObtenerMoneda
        ObtenerMoneda();
        if (MonedaID==1)
        {
            IVA = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            IVA = 0.16;
        }
        #endregion
        #region LLenarGrid
        if (Existe)
        {
            if (articulo != "" && cantidad > 0 && preciounitario > 0 && subtotalArt!=0 && descripcion != "")
            {
                DataRow drArticulosSeleccionados = dtMatrizArticulos.NewRow();
                foreach (DataRow drMatrizArticulos in dtMatrizArticulos.Rows)
                {
                    drArticulosSeleccionados["Articulo"] = articulo;
                    drArticulosSeleccionados["Cantidad"] = cantidad;
                    drArticulosSeleccionados["PrecioUnitario"] = Convert.ToDouble(preciounitario);
                    drArticulosSeleccionados["SubtotalArticulo"] = Convert.ToDouble(subtotalArt);
                    drArticulosSeleccionados["Detalle"] = Convert.ToString(descripcion);                        
                }
                dtMatrizArticulos.Rows.Add(drArticulosSeleccionados);
                subtotalGeneral += subtotalArt;
                if (subtotalGeneral > 0)
                {
                    txtIngSubtot.Text = string.Format("{0:n2}", (Math.Truncate(subtotalGeneral * 100) / 100));
                }
                else
                {
                    txtIngSubtot.Text = "";
                }
                if (IVA > 0)
                {
                    subtotalGlobal = subtotalGeneral * IVA;
                }
                else
                {
                    subtotalGlobal = subtotalGeneral;
                }
                if (IVA > 0 && subtotalGlobal > 0)
                {
                    totalGlobal = subtotalGeneral + subtotalGlobal;
                    txtIvaIngOrden.Text = string.Format("{0:n2}", (Math.Truncate(subtotalGlobal * 100) / 100));
                    txtIngTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:n2}", (Math.Truncate(totalGlobal * 100) / 100));
                }
                else
                {
                    txtIvaIngOrden.Text = string.Format("{0:n2}", (Math.Truncate(IVA * 100) / 100));
                    txtIngTotal.Text = "";
                    totalGlobal = subtotalGeneral;
                    txtIngTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:n2}", (Math.Truncate(totalGlobal * 100) / 100));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (articulo=="")
                {
                    objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Por favor seleccione un artículo para agregar.",true,lblAvisoNOS);
                }
                if (descripcion=="")
                {
                    objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Por favor ingrese los detalles de los artículos a agregar.", true, lblAvisoNOS);
                }
                if (subtotalArt==0)
                {
                    if (cantidad==0 && preciounitario==0)
                    {
                        objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Por favor ingrese la cantidad y precio unitrio de los artículos a agregar.", true, lblAvisoNOS);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (cantidad == 0)
                        {
                            objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Por favor ingrese la cantidad artículos a agregar.", true, lblAvisoNOS);
                        }
                        if (preciounitario == 0)
                        {
                            objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Por favor ingrese el precio unitario de los artículos a agregar.", true, lblAvisoNOS);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dtMatrizArticulos.Columns.Clear();
            dtMatrizArticulos.Rows.Clear();
            dtMatrizArticulos.Columns.Add("Articulo");
            dtMatrizArticulos.Columns.Add("Cantidad");
            dtMatrizArticulos.Columns.Add("PrecioUnitario");
            dtMatrizArticulos.Columns.Add("SubtotalArticulo");
            dtMatrizArticulos.Columns.Add("Detalle");
            if (articulo != "" && cantidad > 0 && preciounitario > 0 && subtotalArt != 0 && descripcion != "")
            {
                DataRow drArticulosSeleccionados = dtMatrizArticulos.NewRow();
                drArticulosSeleccionados["Articulo"] = articulo;
                drArticulosSeleccionados["Cantidad"] = cantidad;
                drArticulosSeleccionados["PrecioUnitario"] = Convert.ToDouble(preciounitario);
                drArticulosSeleccionados["SubtotalArticulo"] = Convert.ToDouble(subtotalArt);
                drArticulosSeleccionados["Detalle"] = Convert.ToString(descripcion);
                dtMatrizArticulos.Rows.Add(drArticulosSeleccionados);
                subtotalGeneral += subtotalArt;
                if (subtotalGeneral > 0)
                {
                    txtIngSubtot.Text = string.Format("{0:n2}", (Math.Truncate(subtotalGeneral * 100) / 100));
                }
                else
                {
                    txtIngSubtot.Text = "";
                }
                if (IVA > 0)
                {
                    subtotalGlobal = subtotalGeneral * IVA;
                }
                else
                {
                    subtotalGlobal = subtotalGeneral;
                }
                if (IVA >0 && subtotalGlobal > 0)
                {
                    totalGlobal = subtotalGeneral + subtotalGlobal;
                    txtIvaIngOrden.Text = string.Format("{0:n2}", (Math.Truncate(subtotalGlobal * 100) / 100));
                    txtIngTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:n2}", (Math.Truncate(totalGlobal * 100) / 100));
                }
                else
                {
                    txtIvaIngOrden.Text = string.Format("{0:n2}", (Math.Truncate(IVA * 100) / 100));
                    txtIngTotal.Text = "";
                    totalGlobal = subtotalGeneral;
                    txtIngTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:n2}", (Math.Truncate(totalGlobal * 100) / 100));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (articulo == "")
                {
                    objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Por favor seleccione un artículo para agregar.", true, lblAvisoNOS);
                }
                if (descripcion == "")
                {
                    objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Por favor ingrese los detalles de los artículos a agregar.", true, lblAvisoNOS);
                }
                if (subtotalArt == 0)
                {
                    if (cantidad == 0 && preciounitario == 0)
                    {
                        objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Por favor ingrese la cantidad y precio unitrio de los artículos a agregar.", true, lblAvisoNOS);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (cantidad == 0)
                        {
                            objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Por favor ingrese la cantidad artículos a agregar.", true, lblAvisoNOS);
                        }
                        if (preciounitario == 0)
                        {
                            objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Por favor ingrese el precio unitario de los artículos a agregar.", true, lblAvisoNOS);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion           
        #region MuestraDatos
        dgvListArtIng.DataSource = dtMatrizArticulos;
        dgvListArtIng.Columns["PrecioUnitario"].ValueType = typeof(System.Decimal);//dgvListArtIng.Columns["PrecioUnitario"].ValueType = Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
        dgvListArtIng.Columns["PrecioUnitario"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##,##0.00";
        dgvListArtIng.Columns["SubtotalArticulo"].ValueType = typeof(System.Decimal);//dgvListArtIng.Columns["SubtotalArticulo"].ValueType = Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
        dgvListArtIng.Columns["SubtotalArticulo"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##,##0.00";
        dgvListArtIng.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Has comprobado que el tipo de las celdas/columnas sea numerico y no `string`? Deberias mostrar la definición del `DataGridView`, asi como la forma en que lo relleneas de datos

Comment: No, no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Intenta `dgvListArtIng.Columns["PrecioUnitario"].ValueType= typeof(System.Decimal)` antes de añadir el formato. Para comprobarlo, depura y mira el valor de `dgvListArtIng.Columns["PrecioUnitario"].ValueType`

Comment: Ya lo intente amigo pero sigue de la misma forma.

Comment: Como te dije,para tener mas claro cual puede ser el problema necesitamos ver _la definición del DataGridView, asi como la forma en que lo rellenas de datos_, ya que es posible que el tipo de datos este en la celda y no en la columna.

Comment: Ya agregue ese dato a mi pregunta.

Comment: Viendo ese código,imagino que no estás definiendo las columnas del DataGridView, sino que tienes activado el AutoGenerateColumns a true. Es posible que venga el problema por ahi, lo mejor es que definas las columnas tu mismo bien por programación o bien desde el diseñador. Ahi puedes configurar el tipo de cada columna y a que columna de tu `DataTable` pertenece cada una

Answer (score 1):

En la propiedad del DatagridView llamado **DefautlCellStyle** configura el **Format** a **C2**.

De esa manera la columna tomara el formato de moneda.

Espero sirva de ayuda para futuras visitas a esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que es pasar a **string** tus variable *(precio unitario, por ejemplo)* a `.ToString("N0")`.

Esto te lo formatea a `10.000.000.`